# VoIP Implementation using Java SIP Library

Tags: java, voip

I want to Implement simple VoIP application using any of the Java SIP Libraries and APIs.can  you give me a simple example of VOIP application. i have not get any resources or tutor that contains 
java Voice over IP.

Comment: For anyone interested it is worth to mention [JVoIP](https://www.mizu-voip.com/Software/Softphones/JVoIP.aspx) here.

Answer (score 8):

[This article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2006/jw-0619-sip.html?page=1) covers this domain very widely.

Comment: That 13-year-old article (2006!) covers the topic of writing low-level Servlet code in Java EE to do things with SIP requests. It is completely not helpful for the more common case of wanting a Java SIP client. JVoip (commercial) and Jitsi (on github and jitsi.org, ASL2 freeware, 95% Java code) may be more useful.

Answer (score 8):

For code samples, you can look at [Jitsi](https://github.com/jitsi)'s source code - it supports VoIP/SIP, along with a number of IM protocols.