# programming portable voip

Tags: java, c++, sockets, portability, voip

I want to create VoIp client side program, but because I don't want to write a different version of the program for different systems I'm choosing carefully my developing platform. Only because I'm very acquanted with C and C++ am I leaning towards C++, however I'm not sure how those C++ libraries will transfer to MAC ... if at all. Java seems more portable, but I'm not sure if they have a framework that I can use on both Mac and Windows as well.

Are there libraries/frameworks that already do the work for me that function on both Mac and Windows for either C++ or Java? I don't want to reinvent the wheel and develop this to be as easy and fast as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038274/voip-implementation-using-java-sip-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Poco library, that is a C++ framework, is cross-platform and have lots o features to work with networks, data streams and much more.

http://pocoproject.org/documentation/index.html

Let a try.